# gunicorn: command not found django

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

Using Docker to install gunicorn, I am unable to to use the gunicorn command.

To start Django, I have this line in my docker-compose.yaml:

```
command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn myproject.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

This results in bash: gunicorn: command not found

When I build the Docker images it says gunicorn has been successfully installed.

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /config
ADD requirements.txt /config/
RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /src;
WORKDIR /src
```

I've been using this http://ruddra.com/2016/08/14/docker-django-nginx-postgres/ as a guide.

Comment: do you install requirement with `pip -r` as well?

Comment: hmm, looks seem you did it in `Dockerfile`

Comment: Yes, RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.txt

Comment: To ensure, go to your container (`dg01` at here) with : `docker exec -it dg01 bash` then do `pip show gunicorn` on its container's command line, if not any thing returned `gunicorn` not installed on your container and else ...!

Comment: Nothing was returned! Do you know where I go from here? @BenyaminJafari

Comment: So you could install `gunicorn` with: `pip install --upgrade gunicorn==19.6.0` at there (on container shell)

Comment: Post your `requirements.txt` does it have `gunicorn` listed? If not then you know the problem

Comment: I added `pip install gunicorn` to my docker-compose.yaml. This fixes the issue, but not the cleanest solution
My requirements.txt inlcudes gunicorn.

Comment: Post the complete build logs then without the `pip install gunicorn` version

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding that gunicorn doesn't exist it could be because
docker image may use a cached layer of the requirements.txt which doesn't have gunicorn in it as a dependency.
Therefore it will result in not installing gunicorn meanwhile specifying `pip install gunicorn` in a seperate `RUN` command will work.

Solution:

Build docker image without caching when edits have been made to requirements.txt

```
docker build --no-cache .
```